# Passing parameters to ->redirect() via $_GET

Tags: atk4

Hi I have this sentence

```
$g->addButton('')->set('NEW ACTIVITY')->js('click')->univ()->redirect('newactivity');
```

Is it possible to call the "redirect" method and passing parameters via $_GET ? so in the page "newactivity" I can ask for $_GET['something'] ?

Something like this

```
$g->addButton('')->set('NEW ACTIVITY')->js('click')->univ()->redirect('newactivity?id=1'); (this doesn't work)

or

   $g->addButton('')->set('NEW ACTIVITY')->js('click')->univ()->redirect('newactivity','id=1');
```

Thanks

Comment: Could be maybe using stickyget ?

Comment: Hi, StickyGET is the answer !!! Thanks anyway. Alejandro

Comment: just curious, why do you use addButton('') and then set the label right after instead of specifying label to addButton directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to properly build destination URL.

http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/page/link

```
->univ()->redirect($this->api->getDestinationURL('newactivity',array('id'=>1)));
```

using stickyGET will affect ALL the urls you are going to produce form this point on. So if you add 2 links, each of them would be passing ID.

stickyGET is better if you need to pass argument which was already passed through GET, such as

```
array('id'=>$_GET['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a place where other ATK4 Developers chat too, perhaps another resource for your ATK4 Q's.  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2966/agile-toolkit-atk4

Comment: asking questions  here is better :) reputation ... mmm.. and it's easier for others to find them.